# Animation of imageView is starting from its center

Tags: ios, swift, animation, cgaffinetransform

I have a UIImageView. I have transformed its height in the animation block. The imageView have autolayout constraints. The initial height of the imageView is set to 0 so that I can achieve a transitionFlipToBottom effect. When the animation block runs, it transforms the height but it starts from the center not from the top.

Here is the code:

```
func Test(){   
    self.imgFitness!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 0)
    self.imgTime!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 1)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: {
    self.imgFitness!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
    }, completion: { (success) in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    self.imgTime!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)}, completion: { (success) in

    })
}
```

Comment: Can you try this before doing the animation: self.imgFitness!.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)

Answer (score 0):

All transforms occurs about the layer's **anchor point**, and default value is at the center.

E.g. when you do the rotate transform, it will rotate around the center. And when you scale, it will scale relative to the center.

Note that the anchor point is in unit space, e.g. between 0 and 1. The default value is (0.5, 0.5) or at the center.

So, try setting it to the top center of your image view before doing the animation:

```
self.imgFitness!.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
```

Comment: yeah but have u actually seen the result of changing anchorPoint of a view which is set through autoLayout? The view gets displaced.